"DELEGATECALL" with value
How is it possible that "DELEGATECALL" with a non-zero value?
Example:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xd697d2db1494197496a8e6312c8295131a1df66bdeafd29be85361f2318832ad/advanced#internal

After I tried to debug_traceBlockByNumber that block (6747896) and really found that
Maybe someone has a quick answer, if no - I can share the debug_traceBlockByNumber code snippet to reproduce via rpc-node.

no need to share any debugs, the parent call already received the value so it is on the balance of the calling contract already. using msg.value with delegate call has no meaning at all since the balance of contract already contains the value, you could use it to know how much was transferred, though

@Nulik thanks for the answer

@Nulik you can post this comment as an answer, with additional info if needed. So that OP can mark it as an answer and anyone can easily find it if needed in the future.

no need to share any debugs, the parent call already received the value so it is on the balance of the calling contract already. using msg.value with delegate call has no meaning at all since the balance of contract already contains the value, you could use it to know how much was transferred, though
For reference:
Call() is declared in the EVM with value parameter:
func (evm *EVM) Call(caller ContractRef, addr common.Address, input []byte, gas uint64, value *uint256.Int) (ret []byte, leftOverGas uint64, err error) {

But DelegateCall() has the value parameter absent , because it is not needed anymore:
func (evm *EVM) DelegateCall(caller ContractRef, addr common.Address, input []byte, gas uint64) (ret []byte, leftOverGas uint64, err error) {

The msg.value is stored in a transaction context variable, so it will stay there until last instruction of transaction is executed
These functions are located in core/vm/evm.go file (of official go-ethereum sources) , if you need more info.
